# Getting value from radio buttons when button has been clicked PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Thank you for taking the time to read my question im new to PHP and taking some time to experiment and learn the language.
Im trying to create my own poll where a user has a choice between 3 different countries which they think will win a certain competition. When the user clicks submit the isset function is triggered which should get the value from the radio button he clicked aswell as show the number of votes for each country thus far.

**Im getting an error undefined index team when I click submit team is the name in my radio buttons**

Im not asking for someone to complete this problem for me but merely point me in the right direction. In my textbook it says you can get the value of any radio button with $_REQUEST superglobal but clearly im doing something wrong.

code follows:

```
 <?PHP if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {        
     $selected_team = $_REQUEST['team'];        
        if($selected_team == 'NZ'){     
           $selected_team ='NZ';
          } 
            else if($selected_team =='AUS')
           {        
              $selected_team = 'AUS'; 
            }
          else if($selected_team =='SA'){   
                $selected_team = 'SA'   
             }
        echo $selected_team;

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `votes`";    
         $result = mysql_query($sql)    
         or die($result."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); 

           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){           
              print "AUS: ".$row['AUS']."<br>";
              print "NZ: ". $row['NZ']."<br>";          
              $row['SA']."<br>"; print "SA:";   
              } 

             else{  
              echo' <form name="poll" method="post"id="poll"> 
                 <label for="NZ">New Zealand</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="NZ" name="NZ" value="team"  /> <br /> 
                 <label for="AUS" style="margin-left:25px">Australia</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="AUS"name="AUS" value="team" /> <br /> 
                 <label for="SA"style="margin-left:3px">South Africa</label>
                    <input type="radio"id="SA" name="SA" value="team" /> <br />
```

Comment: Radio buttons and checkbox only get sent if they have been checked otherwise nothing gets sent. Your value and names need to be switched. Name is what php uses in `$_POST` and the value is what's in `$_POST['team']`

Comment: @Class thank you for your reply, I tried what you suggsted but still no result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of issues.

One of your problems is that you are you assigning the wrong value to the radio button. The `value` is the value of the radio button. So your form should look like:

```
echo' <form name="poll" method="post"id="poll" action="your_next_script.php"> 
             <label for="NZ">New Zealand</label>
                <input type="radio" id="NZ" name="team" value="NZ"  /> <br /> 
             <label for="AUS" style="margin-left:25px">Australia</label>
                <input type="radio" id="AUS"name="team" value="AUS" /> <br /> 
             <label for="SA"style="margin-left:3px">South Africa</label>
                <input type="radio"id="SA" name="team" value="SA" /> <br /> 
             <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Then in your next page the `your_next_script.php`, you can process the form by doing something like:

```
  $selected_team = $_POST['team'];        
        if($selected_team == 'NZ'){     
           $selected_team ='NZ';
          } 
            else if($selected_team =='AUS')
           {        
              $selected_team = 'AUS'; 
            }
          else if($selected_team =='SA'){   
                $selected_team = 'SA'   
             }
        echo $selected_team;
```

You could honestly shorten this to:

```
$selected_team = $_POST['team'];    
echo $selected_team;
```

There is no need for the if/else statements because all you are doing is outputing the value of `$selected_teams`. If you plan on processing the data, like incrementing the votes, you would then need the `if/else` statements

The thing you need to keep in mind that is `PHP` is a server-side script, and just clicking on the radio button won't trigger an action. You have to submit the form, and move to another page to process the data. If you want to process the data without submitting the form, you would need to use javascript, but if you are going to make a poll then you're going to want to have a second page.